# Can you please explain how padleft works in C#

Tags: c#, padleft

Can you please explain me this code -

```
return string.Join(string.Empty, checkSum.Select(x => Convert.ToString(x, 2).PadLeft(8, '0')).
```

checkSum will have binary value like 10101010100011.

Checked in google but didn't find clear explanation.

Comment: It is a lot more obvious when you set checkSum to 3.  Convert.ToString() then generates "11", PadLeft() turns that into "00000011" so it has enough digits to represent the bits in a byte.

Comment: It's hard to explain the `.` at the end.

Comment: I am confused by this code. What is the type of `checkSum` variable? String? One closing parenthesses is missing. If I put it at the end and set `checkSum` to "3" I get `00110011`. Makes no sense.

Comment: Assuming `chackSum` is string, this code converts every character to ASCII binary value, and then concatenates those binary values. What's the point?

Comment: `PadLeft(8, '0')` - we want **at least** `8` characters, if we don't have enough, add `0` from the left

Answer (score 2):

You can find the `PadLeft` documentation here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft

It works by "resizing" the string to a certain length by prepending spaces to make it the desired length. That same page includes this example:

```cs
string str = "BBQ and Slaw";
Console.WriteLine(str.PadLeft(15));  // Displays "   BBQ and Slaw".
Console.WriteLine(str.PadLeft(5));   // Displays "BBQ and Slaw".
```

Your particular code works such that an array of numbers `checkSum` is mapped via `Select` to all be binary numerals not integers (`ToString(x, 2)`) and the binary form is padded to always be 8 characters but not padded by spaces but by zeroes.